# Perl - Add and Modify HTML with pQuery

Tags: html, perl

I'm just a hobbyist Perl programmer learning pQuery and using a local HTML file to aid the process. Here is what I have so far:

```
        use strict;
        use warnings;

        use pQuery;

        my $filename = 'learn.html';
        my $file = pQuery($filename);

        my $metadesc = pQuery("meta", $file)->eq(2);
        my $title = $file->find('title');
        my $h1 = $file->find('h1')->find('a');
        my $h2 = $file->find('h2')->eq(0);

        $title->html('New Title');
        $h1->html('New Heading');
        $h2->html('New Sub-Heading');
```

However, I've hit a bit of a wall and can't quite work out what to do next. What I'd like to do:

1. Modify the "Content" attribute of $metadesc;
2. Add a p inside a div immediately after $h2;

Answer (score 0):

If it were jQuery, I would say 1. use the .attr() method to update the attributes of $metadesc and 2. use the insertAfter method.

But as the module says, it's under construction and "This module is still being written. The documented methods all work as documented (but may not be completed ports of their jQuery counterparts yet)."  So those methods may not be implemented yet.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither attr() nor after() which I assume is the method analogous to insertAfter are implemented yet. Looking in the source they are marked as TODO.